# Laravel seeding with specifically set id

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-seeding

I've got a data from a database as a csv file that includes ids and I need to seed these specific ids into my database. However, everytime I try to seed I get random id's assigned instead.

```
    use CsvLoader;

    /**
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $types = $this->load('types.csv');

        foreach ($types as $type) {
            AirportType::create([
                'id'    => $type[0],
                'type'  => $type[1],
                'name'  => $type[2]
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The above seeder successfully populates the `type` and `name` fields but I get a random id assigned instead of the csv value. This may be to do with my initial migration.

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
        });

        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE types ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();');
        
        app()->make(\Database\Seeders\TypesSeeder::class)->run();
        
    }
```

As you can see I have a default value set to a random uuid generator, which is what I want but I want the initial values to be set as seen in the csv.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the default value for id column in your migration file. This will allow you to specify the id value in your seeder file.

Comment: Hi @chipsy when I do this I get an error saying that id can't be null, so if I change this and add nullable to my id column, my db gets populated with nulls in the id field. So for some reason it still isn't taking the id column of my csv. I know that this column is working as I can populate my 'type' column with my ids for example

Comment: If I do remove this default value, this is the error I get: SQL: insert into "types" ("type", "name", "updated_at", "created_at") values (large, Large 2022-12-07 11:24:34, 2022-12-07 11:24:34) returning "id"), it looks like it doesn't look at id?

Comment: I found the issue, being that in my Model the id is not in my $fillable array, meaning that I was unable to populate it. Is there a way to allow seeders to set this without updating my Model? Sorry I'm new to laravel and not quite sure how to use it yet

Comment: Can you check whether your migration/table structure is correct? Because I did see that you're creating `types` table but, your model is `AirportType` unless you're not using the default naming.

Comment: You could not use the model and just use `DB:table('airport_type')->create(...`